# Trying to multiply two numbers together using only addition

Tags: java, algorithm, loops, for-loop

so I'm trying to make a very simple program but I think I am over thinking it. I want to multiply two numbers together without using multiplication, only addition. I know I will have to add X to itself Y times in order to achieve this, but the way my for-loop is now, it simply adds X to itself once and never again. I know that this algorithm is in the wrong place, but I am unsure where else to put it or what else to do. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class multiply {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int answer = 0;

    Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a value for x");
    x = scan.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please enter a value for y");
    y = scan.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < y; i++){
        answer = x+x;

    }

    System.out.println(x + " multiplied by " + y + " equals " + answer);

}

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is incorrect

```
answer = x+x;
```

should be:

```
answer = x + answer;
```

or

```
answer += x
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! I was being confused by something so simple!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that you are reassigning in each iteration of , you actually need to do like this

## Try this

```
  answer += x;
```